# Google Cloud Networking Issue

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, firewall, google-cloud-networking

I have some services stood up on Google Container Engine and they are hooked up to external IPs.

When I try to query on of these external IPs from within one of my services I get an error like

```
dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:5429: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Using the exact same service, but running on my local machine, it can connect fine to the same IP and port.

Is there some sort of port opening that I need to do in Google Networking dashboard or in my Kuberenetes pod configuration to allow my pod to connect to this host?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a firewall issue. It's in the cloud console dashboard under networking.

Comment: I'll have to look again. I was in that panel for a while but still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

It is a [firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) issue. It is trying to set up a connection through 5429 port, which surely is being blocked in the firewall rules.

You can find the Firewall console in the dashboard > Networking > VPC network > Firewall rules.

You only need to [allow](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) the connection in the needed port in the network where your instance is and it will work properly.

Comment: The [default rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules) for incoming/inbound traffic is "deny all" and the default rule for outgoing/egress traffic is "allow all".  So, you are being blocked by the inbound rule.  You need to open a port, as Katie says.